# Regex match not returning true or false

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match when there is a value with parenthesise.

```
var onsuccess = "aaa;bbb(ccc)";
onsuccess.split(';').forEach(function (success) {
                var re = new RegExp("\(.*?\)");
                document.write(success + ": " + success.match(re) + "<br>");
        });​
```

Output is

```
aaa: ,
bbb(ccc): ,
```

Expected is

```
aaa: false
bbb(ccc): true
```

Where am I going wrong? I have been using this page as an example:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/valamas/8B5zw/

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var onsuccess = "aaa;bbb(ccc)";
onsuccess.split(';').forEach(function (success) {
   var re = /\(.*?\)/;
   document.write(success + ": " + re.test(success) + "<br>");
});
```

***[The working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/XkNBr/)***

***Note:*** if you using `new RegExp(...)`, you need to escape your backslash.

You regex should be `var re = new RegExp("\\(.*?\\)");`, but since there is no variable in your regex, you should just use the regex literal instead.
​

Comment: thanks. I was just wondering what SLaks meant by `swallowed by literal'.

Comment: You should move the "var re = ..." to outside of the loop, just for performance purposes. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12613079/566012

Answer (score 3):

`.match()` returns an array of matching groups.

You're thinking of `.test()`, which returns true or false.

Also, your `\`s are being swallowed by the Javascript string literal.
You should use a regex literal instead.

Comment: `.match()` returns an array (or `null`), not a string?

Answer (score 1):

This was missing a group to match, and a cast to boolean:

```
var onsuccess = "aaa;bbb(ccc)";
onsuccess.split(';').forEach(function (success) {
                //var re = new RegExp("(\(.*?\))");
                var re = /.*(\(.*?\)).*/;
                document.write(success + ": " + !!success.match(re) + "<br>");
        });​
```

Comment: No, regex matches are not anchored to string begin and end in javascript. The expression was just fine

Answer (score 1):

### Use .test instead of casting

```
var onsuccess = "aaa;bbb(ccc)";
var rxParens = /.*(\(.*?\)).*/;

onsuccess.split(";").forEach(function(success) {
    document.write(success + ': ' + rxParens.test(success) + '<br>' );
});
```

---

```
aaa: false
bbb(ccc): true
```

---

Just as a side note, .test performs many times faster than .match http://jsperf.com/exec-vs-match-vs-test/5